# PHP UPDATE script not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement an update script on my page but it doesn't work.
I have 2 pages, the 'update.php' page and the 'update_ac.php' page that runs the script after hitting 'submit' on the Form, the code is as below:

update.php

On this page i have this error : Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\update.php on line 16

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="root"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="764503"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produse WHERE id='$id'");
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>titlu</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>stare</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>pret</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>descriere</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="titlu" type="text" id="titlu" value="<? echo $rows['titlu']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="stare" type="text" id="stare" value="<? echo $rows['stare']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="pret" type="text" id="pret" value="<? echo $rows['pret']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="descriere" type="text" id="descriere" value="<? echo $rows['descriere']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

update_ac.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="root"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="764503"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE produse SET titlu='$_POST[titlu]' ,stare='$_POST[stare]' ,pret='$_POST[pret]' ,descriere='$_POST[descriere]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result)
{
echo "Successful";
}

else 
{
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Comment: missing comma `pret='$_POST[pret]' descriere='$_POST[descriere]'`

Comment: Obligatory mysql is deprecated and your code is wiiiiddddeee open to SQL injection

Comment: If you can't fetch rows, check what $id contains.

Comment: Show us the actual values of which you fetch and try to insert.

Comment: Have you checked the error log? Make sure to turn on all error checking options when developing.

Answer (score 1):

*mysql_query* return FALSE when error occurs instead of returning an Array, this test avoid a second (and bigger) error : if FALSE no problem, if an Array you can fetch it ;oP

```
if ($result) $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Please expand on this answer. A single snippet does not explain anything.

Comment: sorry, mysql_query return FALSE when error occurs (instead of an array) so to avoid such behavior we could test $rows before trying to read it as an array : if it's FALSE ok, if it's an array, the test will respond TRUE

Comment: Edit your post to include this information, please.

Answer (score 0):

This probably means you have an error in your query. If you have an error in your query, it doesnt create a resource to get your data from.

to find an error: add or die(mysql_error()) to your mysql_query command. so you can find out the error.

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your update sql query in the `update_ac.php` file. So nothing is probably getting updated. You are using the array indexes wrong in the following statement:

```
$sql="UPDATE produse SET titlu='$_POST[titlu]' ,stare='$_POST[stare]' ,pret='$_POST[pret]' ,descriere='$_POST[descriere]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'";
```

`$_POST[titlu]` should be `$_POST['titlu']`, `$_POST[stare]` should be `$_POST'stare']` and so on. So the correct query can be as below:

```
$sql="UPDATE produse SET titlu='".$_POST['titlu']."' ,stare='".$_POST['stare']."' ,pret='".$_POST['pret']."' ,descriere='".$_POST['descriere']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'";
```